# Is it normal that an app lags on android emulator and works fine on ios simulator? in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

This is what i get in console when i run it on android emulator . The app runs alright but lags a bit. Is this normal behaviour or do i need to make some changes? Looks like something is not right here but how do i make this work normally?

```
 W/a.myprofil(10897): Accessing hidden method Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->setCurveName(Ljava/lang/String;)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    W/a.myprofil(10897): Accessing hidden method Lsun/security/x509/AlgorithmId;->get(Ljava/lang/String;)Lsun/security/x509/AlgorithmId; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    W/a.myprofil(10897): Accessing hidden method Lsun/security/x509/AlgorithmId;->getName()Ljava/lang/String; (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
    W/a.myprofil(10897): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/BlockGuard;->getThreadPolicy()Ldalvik/system/BlockGuard$Policy; (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
    W/a.myprofil(10897): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/BlockGuard$Policy;->onNetwork()V (greylist, linking, allowed)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's normal, Android Emulator is an emulator and iOS Simulator is a simulator. A simulator take less ressources than an emulator so it will be more smooth on a simulator. But an emulator is better to make tests because it's a real android/iOS environnement.

Comment: Thank you. It  was looking like some problem so had to figure it out.